# Spring Boot WebFlux Save request and response as json

Tags: spring-boot, reactive-programming, spring-webflux

I've used spring webflux as it was suggested to be used for httpClient. now I'm forced to save the request and response (JSON) in DB so I could track the history of service usage. and I don't want to block the response and reduce the performance.
some people have written about actuator, and others suggest using a filter. but until now I have not found a straight answer. Is it good to do something like this at all? and in my case what would be the best way to still keep the non-blocking system running ?
any recommendations ?

Comment: WebFilter is a good solution for this task. For reactive flow the best solution would be to use reactive driver for DB. In case you can't use it, "wrap" non-reactive code and run it on a separate `Scheduler`.Ccheck [How Do I Wrap a Synchronous, Blocking Call?](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#faq.wrap-blocking) for details